# Python : inserting the dataframe into the simpsons 1/3 . equation

Tags: python, dataframe

I here have data that has become the previous flow rate taken from csv data.

```
for i in range(len(interpolated_data)):
   interpolated_data[i] = interpolated_data[i] * 1/4 * np.pi * (0.1068 ** 2)
```

I want the interpolated data to be volume data by means of numerical integration using the Simpson 1/3 method.

```
def simpson13(x0, xn, n, xMiddle):
hasil = x0 + xn + xMiddle
for i in range(1, n):
    hasil = hasil * (n*3)
return hasil
```

which is where the data is divided per day, with the upper limit of the value of `x0` data at the beginning of the day, and `xn` as the value at the end of the day, `n` is the number of data for that day, and `xMiddle` is the middle value.

```
#inisialisasi variabel
volumeDay = [] # array untuk menyimpan volume per hari
dayList = [xArray[0]] # array untuk menyimpan data date setiap hari berbeda
volumeTotal = 0 # data untuk menghitung jumlah volume per hari
x0 = interpolated_data[i]
n = 0
xn = 0
hasil = 0

for i in range(0, len(interpolated_data)): # men-loop data inpData['eTime']
  n += 1
  if (n != 0 and n % 2 == 0):
    hasil += interpolated_data[i] * 2
  else:
    hasil += interpolated_data[i] * 4
  if (i != 0 and (xArray[i].day != xArray[i-1].day) or i == len(interpolated_data) - 1): 
     xn = interpolated_data[i-1]
     volumeDay.append(simpson13(x0,xn,n,hasil)) # masukkan total volume ke array volumeDay
     volumeTotal = 0 # men-reset variabel volumeTotal
     x0 = interpolated_data[i]
     n = 0
     hasil = 0
     if(i != len(interpolated_data)-1): # jika pergantian hari bukan dari indeks terakhir
       dayList.append(xArray[i]) # masukkan data date() ke dalam array dayList

      volumeTotal += interpolated_data[i] #

totalBiaya = 0 # variable to calculate cost per day
for i in range(7): # men-loop 7 kali, untuk 1 minggu
   if volumeDay[i] <= 10: 
      tempBiaya = volumeDay[i] * 7500
   elif volumeDay[i] <= 20:
      tempBiaya = volumeDay[i] * 8750
   else:
      tempBiaya = volumeDay[i] * 11000
   totalBiaya += tempBiaya # menambahkan biaya ke totalBiaya
   print(dayList[i].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),"- Jumlah yang harus dibayar: ",round(tempBiaya,2))
print("Total Biaya: ",round(totalBiaya,2))
```

but what I get is no result, or something like this.

```
2017-07-16 - Jumlah yang harus dibayar:  inf
2017-07-17 - Jumlah yang harus dibayar:  inf
2017-07-18 - Jumlah yang harus dibayar:  inf
2017-07-19 - Jumlah yang harus dibayar:  inf
2017-07-20 - Jumlah yang harus dibayar:  inf
2017-07-21 - Jumlah yang harus dibayar:  inf
2017-07-22 - Jumlah yang harus dibayar:  inf
Total Biaya:  inf
```

i don't know what's going on, can anyone fix and explain why the data doesn't add up?

Comment: 1) Please show your csv file 2) What output do you get if you don't use round?

Comment: attach some reproducible example please.

Comment: I have the following flow speed datasheet. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1akC9YkCNEHHHAunEr6TYJ88Ps_osbCianbH-wiZXSrM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: reproducible example, it will produce daily volume data multiplied by the cost, which results in daily billing costs, I think so.

Comment: if you want to see the full code, here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l50dWs0HR1pwZQxYqIuGEO4AJ1_VewUF/view?usp=sharing)